# FetchRequest not sorting correctly

Tags: ios, sorting, swiftui, core-data

I have a coredata entity called 'Show' with a one to many relationship to another entity called 'Season.' I'm trying to display the seasons of the show in reverse order in a list, so that the most recent season shows at the top. However, my fetch request is not working correctly and sometimes it does sort it correctly up to ~4 or 5, but then it just starts placing them wherever. The seasonNumber attribute on the Season entity is an Int16 if that helps, and I've verified that it is setting them correctly as each time it lists the seasons, it shows the number next to it.

I have tried looking and using the .sorted(by) `List(show.season.sorted(by: show.season.seasonNumber)` but that doesn't work, and Xcode doesn't find seasonNumber.

I've also tried this fetchRequest which is failing to sort it correctly.

```
   // FETCH ALL SEASONS
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [
        SortDescriptor(\Seasons.seasonNumber, order: .reverse)
    ]) var seasons: FetchedResults<Seasons>
```

My List Code:

```
List (show.seasons, id: \.self) { season in
SEASON INFO HERE
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out:

```
 // FETCH ALL SEASONS
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [
        SortDescriptor(\Seasons.seasonNumber, order: .reverse)
    ]) var seasons: FetchedResults<Seasons>
```

and then in the view itself:

```
 List (show.seasons.sorted(by: {$0.seasonNumber > $1.seasonNumber}), id: \.self) { season in
```

Comment: This answer and your question doesn’t make sense, your fetch request fetch Season objects but your List uses a Show object so they have nothing to do with each other. Remove the fetch request altogether.